# With site-wide ssl do I really need to encrypt clear text paypal buttons?

Tags: ssl, encryption, paypal

I have buit a website and as I have enabled ssl every page is https and shows the padlock symbol.

My paying customers (not many as it's for online therapy) have a login username and password and only then do they see a form enabling them to pay me via paypal.

The buttons on the Paypal button factory do not have parameters that are flexible, as my business demands they need to be.

My question is, given the above and that it seems such a pain to such an inexperienced coder as myself, do I really need to encrypt my paypal buttons?

Been going round in circles trying to see how to encrypt buttons for three weeks and to no avail! Server is in safe mode with exec disabled, so running command lines for openssl to encrypt in php pages not an option.

Answer (score 1):

They use the term 'encrypt' rather loosely. What they really mean is that the button is registered with Paypal, and identified by a magic number in your HTML, so that prices and quantities etc. cannot be forged by HTML hackers, because whatever is posted in the form is verified against Paypal's record of the button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply EJP. If however my pages are all https and I use the paypal merchant id instead of my business email address would a hacker still be able to alter amounts - I mean the info is already encrypted isn't it??

Comment: The hacker is sitting at his browser and he can do whatever he can do with the HTML. He can then POST his tampered form values over HTTPS. I'm not talking about MITM attacks.

Comment: OK thanks, if that is so then I have to use encryption.